# Python (Filename + Sha1) generator

Tags: python, hash, sha

I have a problem with my algorithm apparently it skips a lot of `sha1 hashes` when executing.

No problem with the filename, but im having problem with having this output:

`filename`+`sha1`\n

For every each of them. I can guess it`s because of os.walk in some way but im not that expert ATM.

```
    txt = open('list','w')
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_path):
    text = str(filenames)
    for tag in ("[", "]", " ","'"):
        text = text.replace(tag, '')
    text = str(text.replace(',','\n'))
    for i in filenames:
        m = hashlib.sha1(str(text).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        txt.write(text+" "+str(m)+"\n")
txt = txt.close()
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a bit of the output and what's wrong with it?

Comment: Once you have found an answer which works, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This lets other people with your problem know which solution works for you.

Comment: May not fix your problem, but you seem to have a superfluous replace beneath your second `for` loop.  You can use `import re`
`text = re.sub('[\[\]," "]',"",text)` to remove both the `for tag` as well as the line directly below that.

Comment: A bit of output:

`mouse.cfg
mscoree.dll
MSS32.DLL
msvcp60.dll
MSVCRTD.DLL
patchw32.dll
python22.dll
python27.dll
SpeedTreeRT.dll
start.bat
syserr.txt`
**unicows.dll 613e84599f579b43777a1397ceff608a194498fa**
`artpclnt.dll
bdvid32.dll
channel.inf
`
As you can see, just one of many gives me the correct output.

Thanks Solaxun for the tip!

Comment: The above is not particularly useful.  If you could post one example filename that is being skipped, that might be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What looks like a potential issue is that you are converting `filenames`, which is a *list* of each individual *file* in the current folder, into a string and then performing replacements on that list.  I assume what you intended to do instead was replace within each filename *string* those special `tags`.  Try the below.

```
    txt = open('list','w')
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(dir_path):
    for text in filenames:
        text = re.sub('[\[\]," "]',"",text)
        m = hashlib.sha1(str(text).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        txt.write(text+" "+str(m)+"\n")
txt = txt.close()
```

As requested, if you dont' want to use `re`, just do what you had originally done:

```
text = 'fjkla[]  k,, a,[,]dd,]'
for badchar in '[]," "]':
    text = text.replace(badchar,"")
```

Comment: FYI you will need to import re to use this.

Comment: Hey Solaxun, thanks for the answer.
It`s perfect for my case, now it works thank you again.

It is possible to do this without the re lib? JFMI

Comment: @F.Leone NP, glad to help.  You can do it without re using your first approach.  I'll update the answer to show an example.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
txt = open('list','w')
```

to:

```
txt = open('list','a')
```

You are using "w" which overwrites any previous content. You need "a", which appends to the existing file without overwriting.

Comment: not sure if this matters since (appropriate gender pronoun) is not  closing the handle until the loop completes.

Comment: @Solaxun He (_or she_) isn't closing the handle, but 'w' will still overwrite the previous content (therefore erasing any previous strings appended to the file).

Comment: This does break the whole thing. The w is correct in this case since it has to be like this (regenerating files following the for in os.walk)

Comment: @AdiC  I believe this is only an issue when you open the file.  What I was saying is that since the loop completes before the hande is closed, and the file was only opened once, at the top of the loop, I don't think you risk overwriting any data.